# Drupal 6 - Using "menu block" - module

Tags: drupal

I successfully installed the menu-block module and I read on http://www.palantir.net/blog/better-know-module-menu-block-part-i that there is a tab called "Add menu block", but I really can't find it. I use Drupal 6 by the way. I've searched for quite a long time now.
I would be great if someone could give me a tip how to use this module appropriately.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

enne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, the link is http://mysite.com/admin/build/block/add for those of you who also can't find the button.

Greetings,

enne

Answer (score 0):

The "Add menu block" link is on the blocks administration page (right at the top), located at http://mysite.com/admin/build/block.

Comment: Thanks Clive for your help, but I still can't find it. Here's a screenshot of my block site: http://advancedata.ad.funpic.de/block.png You can see here that the module should be activated: http://advancedata.ad.funpic.de/cms.png